# Forward geo coding not working when application using country changes

Tags: java, android, geocoding

I want to find latitude and longitude from address, which is filled by user in a text view.But the function I am using to find latitude and longitude is working fine in my country(India) but it is not finding coordinates when it is tested in SriLanka. I could not find a solution, being searching for so long. Providing the java function below.Please help and thanks in advance

```
public void getLatLngFromAddressDest(String addrs) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    // Address address;
    List<Address> address;

    try {
        address = geocoder.getFromLocationName(addrs, 5);
        if (address != null) {
            if (!address.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("address", "empty");
                Address location = address.get(0);
                double testLat = location.getLatitude();
                double testlng = location.getLongitude();
                Log.d("Lat and Lng---->>>>", testLat + "-----" + testlng
                        + "");
                mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("PassengerLocation",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                // Get a SharedPreferences editor
                mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                mEditor.putLong("DESTLATITUDE",
                        Double.doubleToRawLongBits(testLat));
                mEditor.putLong("DESTLONGITUDE",
                        Double.doubleToRawLongBits(testlng));

                mEditor.commit();
                destinationSet = true;
            } else {
                destinationSet = false;
            }
        } else {
            destinationSet = false;
            Toast.makeText(ActivityBookingDetails.this,
                    "Location not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("getLatLngFromAddressDest", e.getMessage() + "");
        destinationSet = false;
        Toast.makeText(ActivityBookingDetails.this,
                "Location not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: iam also facing the same issue

Comment: if you put the string you are searching in google maps (web) does it produce results?

Comment: Your geocoding service probably does not have a database that includes addresses for Sri Lanka. There are, in fact, places in the world that have not been fully digitized.

Comment: @ Evripidis Drakos :yes its producing results.